# How to show a popup or dialog on click of menu tab of salesforce?

Tags: salesforce, visualforce

I am new to salesforce and there is a requirement to show a popup or dialog box (vf page) on click of menu tabs.

Please guide me if this can be done.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using JQuery on visual force page then you can use `JQuery Dialog` to have pop up.

Please refer this [link](https://jqueryui.com/dialog/).